# Can not install MySQL on my Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation, package-management, mysql

I had trouble installing MySQL server on my laptop. And now if i try installing anything new it gives an error message. I tried most of the sites but could not find a solution to my problem.

When I run `sudo apt-get install -f` I get the following message:

```
 sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.5
Suggested packages:
  tinyca mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-5.5
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 497 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8,719 kB of archives.
After this operation, 31.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 152696 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-server-5.5 (from .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb) ...
groupadd: cannot lock /etc/group; try again later.
addgroup: `/usr/sbin/groupadd -g 139 mysql' returned error code 10. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.5_5.5.32-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: run the following commands `sudo rm /var/cache/debconf/* && sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score -1):

Restart your system, if the problem persists then run, in a console:

```
sudo rm /etc/group.lock /etc/gshadow.lock
```